# How do you make a re-usable component with Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, code-reuse, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Lets say I have a part of my Flask app that I want to pull out and use in multiple different projects.  It has SQLAlchemy models using Flask-SQLAlchemy, as well as views and templates.  I can get the app.route decorators by using a Module, but how can I handle the SQLAlchemy db object?

Since my component needs to be separate, I can't just import the db object.  But I don't think I should create the db object twice.  How would I mix its metadata in with the metadata in the rest of the project?

Answer (score 3):

At first you must share `metadata` and do not use flask-sqlalchemy db.Model as base for you re-usable app.

At second you must recreate all classes with extending them new bases from flask-sqlalchemy for supporting signals, short-cuts and other stuff.

Integrate bases (it may be buggy):

```
def integrate_models(cls, nbase):
        new_bases = list(cls.__bases__) + [nbase]
        new_dict = dict(cls.__dict__)
        new_dict.update(dict(nbase.__dict__))
        return type.__new__(cls.__class__, cls.__name__, tuple(new_bases), new_dict)
```

Example Flask app with sqlalchemy extension:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask
from flaskext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

if __name__ == '__main__':
        from some_model_base import init_metadata
        init_metadata(db.Model.metadata)

        from some_model import SomeClass

        SomeClass = integrate_models(SomeClass, db.Model)

        db.create_all()

        print SomeClass.query.all()
```

Where some_model_base.py:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

def init_metadata(metadata):
    Base.metadata = metadata
```

And some_model.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from some_model_base import Base

class SomeClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  Column(String(50))
```

In this example tested only  db.create_all and SomeClass.query shortcut.

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Hm, I'll need to try this out.  Can you find a way to configure the models in the other module to have a relationship with the models in the main program?

Comment: I think the best way do that - declare in your reusable app base classes or MixIns and then build concrete models subclassing them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `flask.current_app`, it is a proxy object to access the current application, and it is what is used in some extensions. So, your code would look something like this:

```
from flask import current_app
from flaskext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(current_app)
```

and then use your `db` object as you would usually do. But i'm not sure if this would work if the user used your module and also needed to use `flaskext.sqlalchemy`, maybe it would conflict, i'd suggest to test this, to be sure your module will be 100% compatible with any `flask` application.